# Unable to get confidence intervals using broom for a gamlss model with a sigma.formula term

Tags: r, tidyverse, broom

I am fitting a gamlss model with the call:

```
model <- gamlss(formula = formula("y_variable ~ image_name + random(biological_source_name) - 1"),
       sigma.formula = formula("~ biological_source_name - 1"),
       family = "NBI",
       data = na.omit(data))
```

However I get an error when trying to get the confidence intervals using `broom::confint_tidy`:

```
confint_tidy(model)
```

The message is:

```
Error in UseMethod("family") : 
  no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "NULL"
In addition: Warning message:
In vcov.gamlss(object, robust = robust) :
  Additive terms exists in the  mu formula. 
  Standard errors for the linear terms maybe are not appropriate
```

However I get a different error when trying to use `broom::tidy`:

```
broom::tidy(model)
```

The message is:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 73
```

When I fit this model without a `sigma.formula` term, I am however able to get the confidence intervals.

```
model_no_sigma <- gamlss(formula = formula("y_variable ~ image_name + random(biological_source_name) - 1"),
       family = "NBI",
       data = na.omit(data))
broom::tidy(model_no_sigma) # Does produce CI output
```

### Reproducible example

```
    library("gamlss")

example_data <- rbind(
  data.frame(
    y = rnbinom(200, mu = 10, size = 1),
    x = "var_1"
  ),
  data.frame(
    y = rnbinom(200, mu = 20, size = 10),
    x = "var_2"
  )
)

# No estimate sigma
model_1 <- gamlss(formula = formula("y ~ x - 1"),
                data = example_data,
                family = "NBI")
broom::tidy(model_1, conf.int = TRUE)


# Include intercept term for sigma
model_2 <- gamlss(formula = formula("y ~ x - 1"),
                  sigma.formula = formula("~ x"),
                data = example_data,
                family = "NBI")
broom::tidy(model_2, conf.int = TRUE)


# Remove intercept for sigma
model_3 <- gamlss(formula = formula("y ~ x - 1"),
                  sigma.formula = formula("~ x - 1"),
                data = example_data,
                family = "NBI")
broom::tidy(model_3, conf.int = TRUE)
```

### Example output

[image: Screen shot of error output]

Comment: Why not construct a minimal dat-object of similar structure as your real data and show us a complete example?

Comment: @42-, thank you for the suggestion. I have added a simple example that produces the same error.

Comment: I get an error from the `rnbinom` call. `'prob' and 'mu' both specified` (If you have a different function with that name from another library then you need to issue a library call to load it.) Voting to close as equivalent to a typo-caused error.

Comment: And even after correcting the obvious error in the example construction, there is no error from the tidy call. Voting to close as not reproducible. Suggest checking your versions to make sure they are up-to-date.

Comment: @42- yes, there was a typo in output. I fixed this and have attached a screenshot of the error output I get.